# PHP PDO::prepare - what determines the casted type?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

What is the determining entity with regard to how PDO::prepare parameter markers are cast prior to binding?

For example, the following query sent to MSSQL with PDO:prepare:

```
SELECT r.name, p.name, i.[grant] AS permGrant
            FROM  acl AS r
            JOIN  acl AS p ON p.type =  'p'
            AND p.name = :permName
            JOIN  acl AS i ON i.type =  'i'
            AND p.id = i.permissionInstanceRefID 
            AND r.id = i.referenceAclId 
            WHERE r.name =  'Anonymous'
            AND r.type =  'r'
```

When prepared in MSSQL the SQL Profiler logs show the prepared statement as:

```
declare @p1 int 
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 text',N'
            SELECT r.name, p.name, i.[grant] AS permGrant
            FROM  acl AS r
            JOIN  acl AS p ON p.type =  ''p''
            AND p.name = @P1
            JOIN  acl AS i ON i.type =  ''i''
            AND p.id = i.permissionInstanceRefID
            AND r.id = i.referenceAclId
            WHERE r.name =  ''Anonymous''
            AND r.type =  ''r''
            ',1
select @p1
```

In the MSSQL database table p.type is cast as a varchar(25) - what is determining the @P1 parameter to be cast as text (which then of course is incompatible with the equal operator?)

I've worked around my problem already by casting the value in the query that is being prepared, but it's my feeling that I should not have to do this.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date version of PDO? Two reasons come to mind: (a) it is trying to be all-encompassing - "it's a string, better be safe and make it the biggest string possible" (b) it may not be current enough to know that text is deprecated and the max types are much, much, much preferred.

Comment: I am developing with PHP 5.5.4, and it is a fresh install.

Comment: I've been thinking hard on this issue overnight. I think that I may have an idea regarding why SQL server is getting the type cast wrong for this query.

I've noticed that when I do not assign an alias to a field name that SQL correctly casts the parameter types as Int, varChar, etc.

However, when I assign an alias to a table, SQL seems to cast the parameter as text. Regardless of the cast that it's being compared to.

Comment: That seems like a very bizarre limitation - so now you're not allowed to use table aliases in your queries? I knew PDO was weird but that's a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: Well - It seemed to work fine in MySQL. I think that perhaps this may be a MSSQL ODBC Driver problem?

Comment: no idea where the problem lies, sorry.